# count the rows with the same value SQL

Tags: sql

So, I have a `StockDistribution` table that has a `StockBatch`. In my `StockBatch` I have an `mv_id`. Many Stock Batches have the same `mv_id` so I want to count How many `mv_id`s are there in one `StockBatch`

I have tried this:

```
SELECT sd.code, COUNT(*) as count, sb.mv_id
FROM stock_distributions sd
INNER JOIN stock_batches sb ON sd.stock_batch_id = sb.id 
GROUP BY sd.code, sb.merchant_variant_id
```

and even tried this:

```
SELECT sd.code, COUNT(sb.mv_id) as count
```

But it does not work, it returns `1` even though it's supposed to be not `1`.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would work.

Comment: You should use only sb.mv_id in your group by clause. Also in your select you should only select sb.mv_id. Remove the sd.code from select and from group by clause.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Many Stock Batches have the same mv_id so I want to count How many mv_ids are there in one StockBatch

This sounds like aggregation with `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT sd.stock_batch_id, COUNT(DISTINCT sb.mv_id)
FROM stock_distributions sd INNER JOIN
     stock_batches sb
     ON sd.stock_batch_id = sb.id 
GROUP BY sd.stock_batch_id;
```

This is confusing, though.  Is there one row per "stock batch"?  If so, `mv_id` is already stored on that row, so I don't see how there can be multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use COUNT(DISTINCT).

```html
SELECT sd.stock_batch_id
       , COUNT(DISTINCT sb.mv_id) 
FROM stock_distributions sd 
INNER JOIN stock_batches sb 
ON sd.stock_batch_id = sb.id 
GROUP BY sd.stock_batch_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question need more clarity ,please share sample input data and desired output.
if you want to count unique sb.mv_id then replace the count with  `COUNT(DISTINCT sb.mv_id)`

Try with Below code:

```
SELECT sd.stock_batch_id,sb.id, COUNT(sb.mv_id)
FROM stock_distributions sd INNER JOIN
     stock_batches sb
     ON sd.stock_batch_id = sb.id 
GROUP BY sb.id;
```

Comment: You can not select sd.stock_batch_id and sb.id and group by only sb.id ! You would get ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd8e8/2